# Linux How to take hostfile as an input from user and call it into script

Tags: linux, bash, user-input

I am using the below script for pinging the multiple Linux hosts which works perfectly fine if it put the `hostfile` by hardcoding into script itself but i want that to be on user input based.

While i am using `read` the file as an input from user but thats getting fail, please suggest me what i am doing wrong here.

```
#!/bin/bash
read -rsp $'Please Enter your hostFile name: ' target_File
echo $target_File
printf "$(date) Starting the Ping Check...."
function pingHost () {
    target_host=${1}
    ping -c2 ${target_host} >/dev/null 2>&1 &&
    printf "%-20s %-10s\n" "host ${target_host}" "ping SUCCESS" ||
    printf "%-20s %-10s\n" "host ${target_host}" "ping FAILED"
}
#
# Variable "data" seeks the filename containing host list.
data="$(< target_File)"
for line in $data
do
    pingHost ${line} &
done
wait
printf "Completed @=> $(date)"
printf "\n"
```

**While giving the `hostfile` inside the script then it works as follows ..**

```
data="$(< hostfile)" <-- this hard-coded file containing hosts

$ ./ping_parallel.bash
Sun May 22 10:55:24 IST 2022 Starting the Ping Check....

host savfav0194         ping SUCCESS
host savfav0268         ping SUCCESS
host savfav0263         ping SUCCESS
host savfav0196         ping SUCCESS
host savfav0260         ping SUCCESS
host savfav0259         ping SUCCESS
host savfav2088         ping SUCCESS
host savfav2135         ping SUCCESS
host savfav2136         ping SUCCESS
host savfav3088         ping SUCCESS
host savfav0257         ping SUCCESS
host savfav0262         ping SUCCESS
host savfav0261         ping SUCCESS
host savfav0270         ping SUCCESS
host savfav0255         ping SUCCESS
host savfav0265         ping SUCCESS
host savfav0266          ping FAILED

Completed @=> Sun May 22 10:55:26 IST 2022
```

**Failing while trying user input :**

```
Please Enter your hostFile name: target_File
Sun May 22 10:58:54 IST 2022 Starting the Ping Check...../ping_parallel.bash: line 22: target_File: No such file or directory
Completed @=> Sun May 22 10:58:54 IST 2022
```

Comment: Haven't you just missed a `$` to point to the value of the target_File variable rather than to a file named target_File ?

Comment: @Aaron, i didn't get that, can you be more explicit.. apologies for not getting it.

Comment: `data="$(< target_File)"` followed by `for line in $data` is a poor implementation. It is better as `while read -r line; do .... done < "$target_File"`

Comment: Prompting for a filepath isn't user-friendly; it's better to make it an argument: `./myscirpt ./dir/myhostfile`

Comment: change `data="$(< target_File)"` to `data="$(< $target_File)"`

Comment: @ufopilot, that doesn't work as it fails to iterate

Comment: @Fravadona, can you help exemplify this.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, thanks for you remark , however .. will you be able to provide an example as an answer which can benefit here and posterity.

Comment: `data="$(< "$1")"`

Comment: @Fravadona, that doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment and also a good practice to use `while` over `for`, please refer for [bash manual](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) here.

I just modified it with `while`, hopefully it should the Job for you!

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p $'Please Enter your hostFile name: ' target_File
printf "$(date) Starting the Ping Check...."
function pingHost () {
    target_host=${1}
    ping -c2 ${target_host} >/dev/null 2>&1 &&
    printf "%-20s %-10s\n" "host ${target_host}" "ping SUCCESS" ||
    printf "%-20s %-10s\n" "host ${target_host}" "ping FAILED"
}
while read -r line;
do
    pingHost $line &
done < $target_File
wait
printf "Completed @=> $(date)"
printf "\n"
```

### Slight modification with your Script:

```
#!/bin/bash
read -rp $'Please Enter your hostFile name: ' target_File
# Don't use variables in the printf format string. Use printf '..%s..' "$(date)".
printf "Starting the Ping Check %s ....\n" "$(date)"
# You Can Just use function name hence its your choice, i just removed.
# pingHost i changed to "icmp_echo" as i used that 
# function pingHost  () {
icmp_echo  () {
    target_host=${1}
    ping -c2 "${target_host}"  >/dev/null 2>&1 &&
    printf "%-32s %-10s\n" "host ${target_host}" "ping SUCCESS" ||
    printf "%-32s %-10s\n" "host ${target_host}" "ping FAILED"
}
# Use a while loop and the read command. Where The -r option to read prevents backslash interpretation.By default,read modifies each line read, 
# by removing all leading and trailing whitespace characters (spaces and tabs, if present in IFS).If that is not desired, the IFS variable may 
# be cleared
while IFS= read -r line
do
    icmp_echo  "$line" &
# Double quote to prevent globbing and word splitting.
done < "$target_File"
wait
# Don't use variables in the printf format string. Use printf '..%s..' "$(date)".
printf "Completed @=> %s" "$(date)"
printf "\n"
```

Answer (score 1):

Continuing from the comment and request for an answer, you have a number of small issues with your script you should address. First, always paste your script into [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) and fix all problems before posting here (it really is quite good).

The other issues found (some material, some form) are:

- POSIX function definitions are simply `name() { body }`. The word `function` which is a bashism allows for defining functions as `function name { body }`, and yes bash will even accept a combination. For portable scripts always use `name() { body }` only.
- Do not embed expandable text or variables in the `printf` *format-string*. That's what *conversion-specifiers* are for. Don't combine fixed-text with variables in the strings you send through *format-specifiers* in the *format-string*. Fixed text goes in the *format-string* itself, e.g.

**NOT**

```sh
    echo $target_File
    printf "$(date) Starting the Ping Check...."
    #...
    printf "%-20s %-10s\n" "host ${target_host}" "ping SUCCESS"
```

**Instead**

```sh
    printf "%s\n%s Starting ping check...\n" "hostsfile" "$(date)"
    #...
    printf "host %-20s ping SUCCESS\n" "$1"
```

- Validate, validate, validate - especially user-input and filenames
- Don't use `list=$(<file)` and `for i in "$list"; do ... done`, Instead, it is `while read -r line; do ... done < file`

Putting all the pieces together, you can do something similar to the following:

```sh
#!/bin/bash --norc

## function
pinghost() {
    ## validate argument provided
    [ -z "$1" ] && {
        printf "error: no host provided.\n" >&2
        return;
    }
    
    if ping -c2 "$1" >/dev/null 2>&1 ; then       ## check ping success / failure
        printf "host %-20s ping SUCCESS\n" "$1"   ## use fixed-text / specifiers properly
    else
        printf "host %-20s ping FAILED\n" "$1"
    fi
}

## destination hosts, validate filename given and file exists and has non-zero size
if [ -n "$1" ] && [ -s "$1" ]; then
    hostsfile="$1"
else
    printf "error: hostsfile argument required to non-zero size file.\n" >&2
    exit 1
fi

## never embed expandable output in the printf format-string, use proper spedifiers
# printf "$(date) Starting the Ping Check...."

printf "%s\n%s Starting ping check...\n" "$hostsfile" "$(date)"

## loop over each line in hosts file
while read -r host; do
    pinghost "$host"      ## no sense in backgrounding just to wait
done < "$hostsfile"

printf "Completed @=> %s\n" "$(date)"   ## the '\n' belongs in the format-string
```

Let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: thanks for the detailed answer , however its just a for loop which take lot of time if a host list is too large to loop over thus is had chosen to run in in the background so it can quickly loop over. i want to make it run parallel.

Comment: Well, the `ping` tests will take the time they take - period. Whether you handle them sequentially in the loop in a single process, or spawn multiple subshells by backgrounding the processes isn't going to same a significant amount of time -- they all have to go through the same CPU scheduler and pipeline. While you may benefit from having some of the subshells handled by different cores, you use a significant additional amount of processing in just setting up the subshells to call `ping`. Then `wait` requires they all fining before you continue anyway. Up to you, but I'd save the subshells.

Comment: @ David, thanks for the significant explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You said that dosen't work (changing `data=$(< target_File)` to `data=$(< $target_File)`)

```
$ target_File=hosts.txt
$ data=$(< target_File)
bash: target_File: No such file or directory
$ echo $data

$ data=$(< $target_File)
$ echo $data
google.com amazon.com

# seems to be fine
$ for x in $data; do echo pingit $x; done
pingit google.com
pingit amazon.com
```

##### read

```
$ read target_File
hosts.txt
$ data=$(< $target_File)
$ echo $data
google.com amazon.com
```

Comment: ufopilot, i don't want `host.txt` to be haed-coded rather it shoul be an user input, where you are defining it in the script that's what i don't want.

Comment: @user294110 that was just a test to show u it does work.. read will be the same